# How to install latest version of FFmpeg on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I'm currently developing an application that shells out to FFmpeg which will run on Ubuntu in the cloud.

I want to install the current version (at the time of this writing, 6.1).

If I run `sudo apt install ffmpeg`, I get version 4.2.7:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
```

Now, I know I can install this manually using the static builds (referenced from ffmpeg.org):

https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

But as mentioned, this will be used in the cloud, and the application is built in Docker, so I'd like to avoid manually installing in the Dockerfile (switching on architecture) and use some sort of package manager for this.

Looking at Launchpad (which is what ffmpeg.org points to for Ubuntu):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg

It seems there is a current stable release which I should be able to install:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:6.0-6ubuntu1

But I am unsure of how to use this platform in order to install it.

Is there some sort of automated/package manager approach I can use to install the latest version of FFmpeg without having to manually manage the underlying architecture.

Or, if I have to manage it manually, how might I best go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [GAD3R](https://askubuntu.com/users/498780/gad3r)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497843/how-to-install-latest-version-of-ffmpeg-on-unbuntu?noredirect=1#comment2623815_1497843), later versions of `ffmpeg` are not supported on Ubuntu versions below 23.10.

Updating to 23.10 and reinstalling `ffmpeg` (it may be updated automatically depending on how it is installed) installs version 6.

Comment: I don't know about (not)supported FFMpeg on Ubuntu. I followed [FFMpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki) [guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) to see how to compile FFMpeg on particular OS distributions. You just need to be OK with compiling from sources. Particularly for Ubuntu, see the [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).